# local host ssl socket without certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate

Would like to write SSL Socket client server application on the same machine (both server and clients are running same machine). Should I use SSL certificate file (.pem file ) or not required.

Just I want encrypt the data before sending via socket.

Can we encrypt the data without .pem file?

Please advice me.

-Bala

Comment: What language\shell are you working in?

Answer (score 0):

SSL has two major steps:

1. check the identity of the peer, e.g. make sure you talk to the right one and not an imposter (e.g. man in the middle). This is done with certificates.
2. encrypt the connection, so that anybody listening on the wire cannot understand what's going on. Obviously encryption helps nothing if somebody is actively listening on the wire, because you failed in step#1. In this case you have no end-to-end encryption but an end-to-imposter and imposter-to-end encryption :)

Considering these arguments: do you still want to skip checking the certificate?
If you want it is doable, just look for anonymous authentication, e.g. ADH or aNULL with openssl.